# Android Background Task Scheduler

Tags: android, task, delay, fixed

I want to schedule a task in Android that runs after every 15 minutes. The precision may vary at the most by +/- 30 sec, but not more than that. The methods Timer.schedule and ScheduledFuture.scheduleWithFixedDelay  are not precise when the device is not awake. I need assurance that the task will always run every 15 min even when the device is in sleep mode. Please suggest all possible approaches.

Answer (score 4):

Use AlarmManager for [repeating alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanx mighter. Just one question, how much impact will an AlarmManager have on the battery, assuming that a simple toast is displayed on every alarm?

Comment: It's not the AlarmManager itself impacting the battery, but the operations you're performing.Try using setInexactRepeating(). Waking device is not recommended anyway.